# Unity3d code error - Vector3

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

> Assets/Scripts/Test.js(9,46): BCE0051: Operator '*' cannot be used
>   with a left hand side of type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' and a right hand
>   side of type 'Object'.

I get this error whenever I try to compile my code. I was changing some code from C# to UnityScript but I keep getting this error. Please help.

```
#pragma strict

static var speed;
function FixedUpdate (speed ) {

    var moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    var moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    var aPosition =  Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical );
    rigidbody.AddForce(aPosition * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined what the variable **speed** is.

Fix - **static var speed : float = 10;**

Answer (score 0):

You are defining 'speed' on 2 different places, as a property and as a parameter to the function. Either remove the 'static var speed;' line of code and call the FixedUpdate with a number, or remove the 'speed' parameter from the function definition and define speed as Venkat said.